# What base color should I set when making emission or transmission effect in Principled BSDF?

Tags: materials

It seems like base color will have some effect on the material, even I aim to make an emission or transmission effect.
I would like to know the physically proper way to set up my material.  According to Blender's official manual, base color represents diffuse or metal surface color. Hence, I think I should avoid using base color when making emission or transmission effects.

Is leaving base color black a proper way? Or should I do some specific setting?

Comment: Hello ! If you're not going to use the principled capabilities, you might as well use an Emission, Glossy, Glass, Refraction or Translucent shader

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The base color affects light *reflected* by the surface.  If you want untinted transmission, set the base color to an RGB value of (1.0, 1.0, 1.0).  Any other value will tint the result, like tinted glass. This works precisely the way that photographic filters affect the light passing through them.

Because it only affects light reflected by the surface, the base color does not affect emission directly.  If you make the emission strength high enough compared to other light sources, you will see nothing but that color.  If you make the strength lower, you will see a combination of reflected light plus emission.